# Pandas DataFrame - How to get most recent value for each column when grouped by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Alright guys, I'm stumped. To be completely honest, I'm very new to manipulating dataframes using pandas.

Suppose I have the dataframe below where the most recent entry is at the top, in descending order (I've already accomplished that part in my program based off of the data I have available).

We'll call it 'df_people' and it contains this data:

```
username    first   middle      last
jschmoe     joseph  NaN         schmoe
jdoe        jane    marie       doe
jschmoe     joseph  michael     schmoe
jdoe        jane    NaN         doe
tuser       test    NaN         user
```

I am trying to parse this down to only show the most recent valid data from each column based off of the 'username' column (or of course leave 'NaN' if there are no valid entries)

Expected result:

```
username    first   middle  last
jschmoe     joseph  michael schmoe
jdoe        jane    marie   doe
tuser       test    NaN     user
```

In my actual dataframe I will have anywhere from 5-100 columns and easily over 100k rows whenever I need to run this report. While I don't expect anything to be *super* fast for what I'm trying to accomplish, I just wanted to give scale so you can understand how even small optimizations can make a big difference. Reliable results is always more important than having the report finish a few seconds faster! Right now I have no results...so anything is better than that...

I've tried out a ton of different combinations of things by scraping through this site and the pandas documentation, but I think my lack of knowledge on what all pandas is capable of is severely limiting here.

Any recommendations or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't the first row of the expected result be: `jschmoe     joseph  NaN         schmoe`, i.e. the most recent entry for the username `jschmoe`?

Comment: No. For this (admittedly simplistic) sample, this is the expected result. I want it to find the most recent non-NaN result for each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df.groupby('username', as_index=False).first()
  username   first   middle    last
0     jdoe    jane    marie     doe
1  jschmoe  joseph  michael  schmoe
2    tuser    test      NaN    user
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain I tried this at one point because a groupby function was the first thing I thought of. I'll give it a shot again and see if maybe there was another reason this didn't work in my data, and maybe I need to expand on the sample dataset to explain.

Comment: I think I was having issues before because I didn't have the "as_index=False" in there, which was throwing off other things later on when trying to work with the results. Such a simple thing...but man that caused me so much frustration! It's always the little nuances...

Answer (score 0):

You can use drop_duplicates,

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='username')
```

Or use groupby

```
df.groupby('username', sort=False).first().reset_index()

    username    first   middle  last
0   jschmoe     joseph  michael schmoe
1   jdoe        jane    marie   doe
2   tuser       test    NaN     user
```

Comment: Duplicates can't work in my case. This is a really small sample dataset to get the gist, but values can change over time and will not always be the same, and may return to old values at a later date

Comment: You are only checking duplicates based on 'username'. It should work as long as you want to get the first record with each unique username.

Comment: I don't want the first entire record though. In the sample provided, dropping duplicates would leave username jschmoe with NaN for 'middle name' as that was the most recent record.

Your groupby example was something I had tried before, but the 'as_index=False' suggested above was the component I was missing when I landed on this before.

Thank you for the suggestions though! They may help other people for their use cases down the line